# How do you describe a vegetarian item? As in a vegetarian burrito?

Tags: grammar

So, in english when describing whether something is friendly for vegetarians or not we say "vegetarian **object_____**". Is there an equivalent in Chinese? 
For example could you say "素的墨西哥卷“？

Comment: Remember in Chinese, "的" is usually used to connect two long words, like "非常美味的墨西哥卷" but not "非常美味墨西哥卷", "香酥鸡" but not "香酥的鸡"。

Comment: Remember to explain that you don't eat meat due to "religious reasons". It will save you a lot of time and effort.

Comment: So you think that 苏的墨西哥卷 sounds a bit wrong?

Comment: It's not wrong, just we don't usually speak in this way. It's like "my little brother" equals "the brother, the little one, of mine" but we use the former. “素的墨西哥卷” is more colloquial, for example "我想吃一个素的墨西哥卷". When comes to a menu, it will be "素墨西哥卷" or "全素墨西哥卷".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Mandarin, we use the prefix "素".

In Cantonese, we use the prefix "齋"

And the order is significant too:

- "素墨西哥卷" implies that the original burrito contains meat and this one is a customized version for vegetarian.
- "墨西哥素卷" implies that this vegetarian burrito is original Mexico food.

On the other hand, as wuyefeibao mentioned, you can add "的" in the phrase; and it is quite interesting in this case:

- "墨西哥的素卷" == "墨西哥素卷"
- "素的墨西哥卷" .... It can be both.  ^_^

Comment: Henry, but would you say that adding 的 sounds unnatural?

Comment: To be even more confusing, "墨西哥的素卷" sounds odd while "素的墨西哥卷" doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

You're on the right track, but don't expect to be completely understood one hundred percent of the time - I've noticed that vegaterian stuff is not exactly a concept in Chinese.

素面

*ABC*

> vegetarian noodle dish

So we have the pattern, like you wrote above just minus the 的, 素 + OBJ.

You can say 素墨西哥卷 but I would just say 素卷 for simplicity.

Comment: And this is down voted, why?